# The add menu callback function doesn't work in wordpress mvc ? Why?

Tags: wordpress, model-view-controller, callback, menu

I am newbie in wordpress mvc of https://www.wordpress-mvc.com/. When I try to add a new menu in plugin, a menu appears. But the callback function ideapro_scripts_page doesnt' work.

In Main.php

```
public function on_admin()
{
    $this->add_action( 'admin_menu', 'MenuController@adminMenu');
}
```

In Menucontroller.php:

```
public function adminMenu()
{       
    add_menu_page('Header & footer scripts', 'Site scripts', 'manage_options', 'ideapro-admin-menu', 'ideapro_scripts_page', 'dashicons-editor-table', 200);
}

function ideapro_scripts_page()
{
    ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>
                Update Scripts on the header and footer
            </h2>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

ideapro_scripts_page() function doesn't show anything in web. What is wrong in it?

Answer (score 0):

**In Your Menucontroller.php**

```
    public function adminMenu(){
       add_menu_page( 
          'Mobile Api Events',
           'Mobile Api Events',
           'manage_options',
           'mobile-api-events',
           array($this,'render' ),
       );
    }
    public function render(){
       return $this->view->show('admin');
    }
```

in view/admin file you can write the html code